# Deserialize Base64 JSON string into Protobuf

Tags: java, json, base64, protocol-buffers

I have a Kafka-Consumer which receives a JSON message from a Kafka Broker. The key "payload" in JSON message has a Base64 Google Protocol Buffer Object stored as its value. i.e the object message is serialized with Google Protocol Buffer and encoded with Base64 and send by the Kakfa-Producer to a Kafka-Broker.

I can receive the JSON message from the Kafka-Consumer but i am facing difficulties in decoding and de-serialising the object with key "payload". At first i have changed the received message to a JSONObject, then i have fetched the value from the key "payload". Then i have decoded the value with Base64 decoder to generate byte array. Then the generated byte array is used to create a ByteArrayInputStream which is then passed as a parameter to ObjectInputStream constructor. Finally, i have casted this ObjectInputStream to the desired Google Protocol Buffer object for deserialization.

I am getting "java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 123E0A24" while reading the
ObjectInputStream  object. I have included the json message format and code below below:

// JSON Message
{
"messageTimestamp":"2021-08-01T12:10:07Z",
"tenantId":"test123",
"objectUuid":"b1602572-156e-4476-96d8-283b2d23ecfa",
"deviceUuid":"a512a4f0-f582-48a3-9001-64487f6c5288",
"activationId":"test3258",
"payload":"Ej4KJGIxNjAyNTcyLTE1NmUtNDQ3Ni05NmQ4LTI4M2IyZDIzZWNmYRIWChRSw7x0dGVscGxhdHRlIEJPTUFHIBoJCgcI6MOuhrovIj8KBwjow66Gui8SCQkhv5FTThVIQBoJCfJ0wfNlaDBAIgAoAjADOgIIB0IJCQAAAOCjcOU/SgkJAAAAANej8D8qAhoAOgIKAEIMCgQItbsBEgQIvYMHShYKEGRpc3RhbmNlRnJvbUxhc3QSAhgCSg8KCWlzRHJpdmluZxICIAA="
}

//Kafka Consumer Code

```
package com.kafka.project;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Base64;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Properties;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.CommonClientConfigs;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecords;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer;
import org.apache.kafka.common.config.SaslConfigs;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import com.google.common.primitives.Bytes;

import io.confluent.kafka.serializers.protobuf.KafkaProtobufDeserializer;
import io.confluent.kafka.serializers.protobuf.KafkaProtobufDeserializerConfig;

public class consumer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Logger logger= LoggerFactory.getLogger(consumer.class.getName());  
        String bootstrapServers="localhost:9092";  
        String grp_id="test-id";  
        String topic="test";  
        String username = "admin";
        String password = "admin";
        
        //Creating consumer properties  
        Properties properties=new Properties();  
        properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,bootstrapServers);  
        properties.put(CommonClientConfigs.SECURITY_PROTOCOL_CONFIG, "SASL_SSL");
        properties.put(SaslConfigs.SASL_MECHANISM, "PLAIN");
        properties.put(SaslConfigs.SASL_JAAS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username=\"" + username + "\" password=\"" + password + "\";");
        properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,   StringDeserializer.class.getName());  
        properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,StringDeserializer.class.getName());  
        properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG,grp_id);  
        properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG,"earliest");  
        //creating consumer  
        KafkaConsumer<String,String> consumer= new KafkaConsumer<String,String>(properties);  
        //NormalizedDeviceDataProtos.NormalizedDeviceData.getDefaultInstance().getPosition();
        
        //Subscribing  
        consumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList(topic));  
       
        //polling  
        while(true){  
            ConsumerRecords<String,String> records=consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(100));  
            
            for(ConsumerRecord<String,String> record: records){
                
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(record.value());                      
                byte bytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(json.getString("payload"));
                
                ObjectInputStream in;
                try {
                    in = new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));
                    try {
                        
//ExampleProtocolBuffer.messageData is a java class generated by "protoc" compiler and "messageData" is a message name in ".proto" file
                        
ExampleProtocolBuffer.messageData message = (ExampleProtocolBuffer.messageData) in.readObject();    
logger.info("Decoded FirstName: " + message.getName.getFirstName());
in.close();
                        
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    }                        
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
                          
      }      
    } 
}

}
```

Comment: Removed Kafka tag since it isn't relevant to parsing the actual base64 string. Read [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer the docs - https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/javatutorial#parsing-and-serialization

Take a look at [`Parser#parseFrom(byte[] data)`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java/com/google/protobuf/Parser.html#parseFrom-byte:A-), which is a method that your message type should have.

ObjectInputStream is for Java serialized Objects, not Protobuf

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion. As per your suggestion, i used Parser#parseFrom(byte[] data) defined in the docs, and it worked. Thanks a lot.

Comment: If this answered your question, please use the checkmark next to the post to accept it